# Tool for streaming multiple pre-recorded videos synchronously as if they were live ip camera's

Tags: synchronization, video-streaming, rtsp, rtmp

I'm testing some code which takes multiple rtsp/rtmp video streams as input and does some person detection and mapping in 3d space. I want to run test scenario's with real or simulated footage that I want to feed into the program as if they are real and synchronized ip camera streams.

For instance: 4 videos of the same scene, from different angles, starting at the same time and with equal duration.

Is there any easy to use tool out there for this job? I'm new to video streaming and I don't know a lot about the workings of the protocols.

Comment: Please include the code you are testing or some kind of stand-alone case.  Are you trying to test your code?  or test whether you can get this to work from a human experience perspective?  please add more detail

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer myself over here:
https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/guides/how-to-stream-local-video-using-obs-and-mistserver

MistServer does the server part and allows setting up multiple stream and OBS pushes to the streams. The OBS application allows selection of videos and with pause/play/rewind allows for manual synchronization